# Powershell Script to get list of local admins on multiple remote PC's

Tags: arrays, powershell, hostname, computer-name, read-host

I almost have this but getting an error when inputting multiple computer names through the prompt input separated by comma. Individual computer name works.

```
$hostname = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter PC names (separated by comma)"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname -ScriptBlock{Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators"} | Export-Csv C:\temp\localadmins.csv
```

When running it without the Read-Host prompt, it works fine to input multiple separated by comma, but when using prompt input and entering multiple computer names it comes back with "one or more computer names are not valid". I'm expecting to to convert the $hostname from the input given over to the -ComputerName exactly as its typed in the input, but I think I'm missing something.

Error Output:

```
Enter PC names (separated by comma): computername1, computername2
Invoke-Command : One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri parameter, or pass URI objects 
instead of strings.
At \\usblfs003.global.baxter.com\users$\parksd2\docs\Scripts\LocalAdminsExport_EntitlementReview.ps1:2 char:1
+ Invoke-Command -ComputerName "$hostname" -ScriptBlock{Get-LocalGroupM ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.String[]:String[]) [Invoke-Command], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionInvalidComputerName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Comment: What happens if you use `-ComputerName ($hostname -split ',')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When running it without the `Read-Host` prompt, it works fine to input multiple separated by comma

That is because something like the following:

```bash
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1, server2 -ScriptBlock …
```

uses an **array *literal*** (via `,` the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-)) to specify the individual computer names that bind to the `[string[]]`-typed `-ComputerName` parameter of the [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) cmdlet.

By contrast, **what [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) returns is *invariably a string*** (a `[string]` instance), so using the response from the user typing `server1, server` in response to the a `Read-Host` prompt is equivalent to using 
`… -ComputerName 'server1, server2' …`
which *cannot work*: it tells `Invoke-Command` to look for a *single* computer whose name is *verbatim* `server1, server2`

**To interpret a *string* as a *list of values* delineated by a *separator*, you need to *explicitly convert it to an array***:

```bash
# Simulate a Read-host call
$hostnameListString = 'server1, server2'

# Convert the user input to an *array*
$hostnames = ($hostnameListString -split ',').Trim()

# Now you can pass the $hostnames array to Invoke-Command
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostnames -ScriptBlock {
  Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators
} |
  Export-Csv C:\temp\localadmins.csv
```

Note:

- `-split ','` uses the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator to split the input string into tokens by `,`
- `.Trim()`, applied to the resulting *array* of tokens, uses [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration), to strip any leading or trailing whitespace from each element.

Comment: This works, thank you for the additional detail as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ADComputers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Select-Object Name
foreach ($ADComputer in $ADComputers)
    {
    $ComputerName = $ADComputer.Name
    Write-Host -Object "Processing groups on $ComputerName" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {Get-LocalGroup -Name Administrators | ForEach-Object {Get-LocalGroupMember -Group $_.Name}} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Could you say more about why this can achieve the OP's goal?

Comment: Your answer (a) doesn't address the specific problem described in the question, (b) adds additional commands without explanation, and (c) presents a distinctly inferior solution, by switching from parallel to sequential processing.